# Add method to arraylist and invoke method dynamically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, selenium-webdriver

I have added method to arraylist and trying to call method (ui.mList.get(0) see code sample 1) in main to execute but java does not execute any method. However, I found other sample code to execute method as give below (see code sample 2), but when I run the code system display exception

### code sample 1:

```
class UserLogin{
List<String> mList = new ArrayList();

public void testAnswerCorrect(){
//My code
}

public void listMethodsUsingReflection(){
Class personClass = UserLogin.class;
Method[] methods = personClass.getDeclaredMethods();
int i=0;
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if(method.getName().toString().contains("test")){
            mList.add(i,method.getName());
            i++;
            }
        }
```

}

```
public static main(String arg[]){

    UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
    ul.listMethodsUsingReflection();
    ul.mList.get(0);
}
```

Running above code does not do anything.

### Sample code 2

```
            Object obj = null;
    UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
    ul.listMethodsUsingReflection();
    String className = "com.test.script.UserLogin";
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    obj = c.newInstance();
    Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
    String sMethod =ul.mList.get(0).toString();
    Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(sMethod, argTypes);
    method.invoke(obj, null);
```

Running above code system give exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:com.test.script.UserLogin.testAnswerCorrect([Ljava.lang.String;)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.test.script.UserLogin.main(UserLogin.java:180)
```

Is something missing or there is some other way to execute method. Also, I will be adding all the method in array list which will be read from xml file and need to execute the code dynamically. Method name will be given by user at the time to writing test script/code.

I would appreciate your inputs

Thanks,

Comment: Well the reason the code in the top section doesn't do anything is that when you create an instance of your class UserLogin, nothing happens as there is no constructor. Try moving your code within the UserLogin class into a UserLogin constructor (then it will actually execute).

Comment: Please note that the object you're invoking it on is a `UserLogin` instance, so ensure there is a method `testAnswerCorrect(String[])` in the UserLogin class (It's not visible in the code you posted).

Comment: @Colin, Chronio: I have update my code, sorry I missed few lines. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `testAnswerCorrect()` method takes no parameters, while you're reflectively trying to access the method `testAnswerCorrect(String[])`. If you change the line

```
Class[] argTypes = new Class[] {String[].class};
```

to

```
Class[] argTypes = new Class[0];
```

then it should work. Note that `testAnswerCorrect()` and `testAnswerCorrect(String[])` are considered to be different methods. You're trying to get the method that takes a `String[]`, and that method does not exist.

Alternatively, you can just get the method like this:

```
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(sMethod);
```

and then you don't have to create the `Class[]` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, after making modification perfectly given by you... my problem got solved... many thanks!!!

Comment: Just want to know that, if there is parameters in method than I have to use 'Class[] argTypes = new Class[] {String[].class};' regardless to any number of parameter in method and do I have to pass any value in 'Class[]'? Thanks

Comment: @Dani If your method has parameters (for example a String[]), then you can get the Method like this: `c.getDeclaredMethod(sMethod, String[].class);`. The `getDeclaredMethod` method can take any number of arguments after the method name as the parameter types of the method you want to invoke (it's a varargs method).

Answer (score 1):

For the example i assume that you have 
    List methodList;

Which is full in methodNames.(This method without parameters

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < methodNames.size() ; i++) {
   Class cls = UserLogin.class;
   Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodNames.get(i));
   Object returnObject = method.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[]{});
}
```

It should be something like that.. AS You can see, Get declared method shouldn't be with String[] like you wrote. your method not getting anyParameter.. So is couldn't be found because you defined to get method with parameter String[]
First you get the Class of your specific method, then you create the method by String of her name, Than you need to invoke your method and get return object.. In case you have paramters you need to fill new

```
Object[]{}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I have made the changes based on your inputs and it also worked with your inputs. Many thanks!!!! :)